# My hard is 512bytes per sector one not 4k, do I still have to force minitool to align it?

Tags: hard-drive

I am hoping to migrate my XP OS to an 80GB SATA hard disk with minitool wizard but there is an option to force it to do 1mb alignment. My hard is 512bytes per sector one not 4k. Do I still have to force minitool to align it that way? To tick or not?

Also, does minitool migration delete the OS from the original disk?

According minitool wizard website XP doesn't support such a sector size. So will it be beneficial for an XP OS and couple of years old SATA hard disk or will it be harmful for the disk and the OS?

Minitool wizard website says the forcing is for new 4K disks

https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmagic/align-partition-for-windows-xp.html

https://www.partitionwizard.com/help/migrate-os-to-ssd-hd.html

Comment: I think you meant 512 bytes. The 1mb alignment is due to the internal memory paging system your drive uses. Alignment will minimize the amount of reads/writes needed per IO operation.

Comment: So will it be beneficial for an XP OS and couple of years old SATA hard disk or will it be harmful for the disk? 

Minitool wizard website says the forcing is for new 4k disks

https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmagic/align-partition-for-windows-xp.html

Comment: If your HDD has 512 byte sector size you dont need any alignment, even if you will do this, nothing harmful at all, just loosing 1Mb of space that can't be used, which is nothing to compare to 80Gb